# I cannot find java.lang.isolate.Isolate

Tags: java

I am using jdk8 and I want to use java.lang.isolate.Isolate to isolate the running of applications. However, it seems there is no java.lang.isolate.Isolate in jdk8 and jdk13.

Please see the showup in my eclipse.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAue0.png)

Comment: The isolate package does not appear to be part of the jdk8, nor any other official version. You need to add the appropriate library to your application that provides this package before you can use it. If this is a homework question then you should have been provided with the library/package that you need.

Answer (score 4):

That is because [JSR 121](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=121) (Application Isolation API Specification) never got implemented.

See [JDK-4599433](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4599433) (provide support for isolation API (JSR-121)):

> Status: **Closed**
> Resolution: **Won't Fix**
> Fix Version/s: **7**